# Problems with installing SQLite3 and Node-Gyp

Tags: python-2.7, discord.js, node-gyp, better-sqlite3

I have been working on getting a new databases and I have been stuck on the same error.

I tried Ito reinstall Python, node.js, etc. But none of these worked
This is my error.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   'better-sqlite3' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose npm-session b6505604cfa596f6
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/better-sqlite3 51ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for better-sqlite3@latest fetched in 168ms
9 silly install loadIdealTree
10 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
11 silly install loadShrinkwrap
12 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
13 silly resolveWithNewModule better-sqlite3@5.0.1 checking installable status
14 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar 82ms (from cache)
15 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/integer 86ms (from cache)
16 silly pacote range manifest for tar@^4.4.6 fetched in 88ms
17 silly resolveWithNewModule tar@4.4.7 checking installable status
18 silly pacote range manifest for integer@^2.1.0 fetched in 94ms
19 silly resolveWithNewModule integer@2.1.0 checking installable status
20 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minipass 65ms (from cache)
21 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp 68ms (from cache)
22 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chownr 82ms (from cache)
23 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-minipass 84ms (from cache)
24 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yallist 75ms (from cache)
25 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minizlib 78ms (from cache)
26 silly pacote range manifest for mkdirp@^0.5.0 fetched in 81ms
27 silly resolveWithNewModule mkdirp@0.5.1 checking installable status
28 silly pacote range manifest for chownr@^1.1.1 fetched in 96ms
29 silly resolveWithNewModule chownr@1.1.1 checking installable status
30 silly pacote range manifest for fs-minipass@^1.2.5 fetched in 96ms
31 silly resolveWithNewModule fs-minipass@1.2.5 checking installable status
32 silly pacote range manifest for minipass@^2.3.4 fetched in 94ms
33 silly resolveWithNewModule minipass@2.3.5 checking installable status
34 silly pacote range manifest for yallist@^3.0.2 fetched in 94ms
35 silly resolveWithNewModule yallist@3.0.2 checking installable status
36 silly pacote range manifest for minizlib@^1.1.1 fetched in 119ms
37 silly resolveWithNewModule minizlib@1.1.1 checking installable status
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist 7ms (from cache)
39 silly pacote version manifest for minimist@0.0.8 fetched in 11ms
40 silly resolveWithNewModule minimist@0.0.8 checking installable status
41 silly pacote range manifest for better-sqlite3@^4.1.1 fetched in 29ms
42 silly resolveWithNewModule better-sqlite3@4.2.0 checking installable status
43 silly currentTree chickenbot@0.0.1
43 silly currentTree +-- @types/better-sqlite3@3.1.3
43 silly currentTree +-- @types/integer@1.0.0
43 silly currentTree +-- ansi-styles@3.2.1
43 silly currentTree +-- async-limiter@1.0.0
43 silly currentTree +-- better-sqlite-pool@0.1.2
43 silly currentTree +-- better-sqlite3@5.0.1
43 silly currentTree | -- integer@2.1.0
43 silly currentTree +-- bindings@1.3.0
43 silly currentTree +-- chalk@2.4.1
43 silly currentTree +-- chownr@1.1.1
43 silly currentTree +-- color-convert@1.9.3
43 silly currentTree +-- color-name@1.1.3
43 silly currentTree +-- discord.js@11.4.2
43 silly currentTree +-- enmap@4.3.3
43 silly currentTree +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
43 silly currentTree +-- fs-minipass@1.2.5
43 silly currentTree +-- graceful-fs@4.1.15
43 silly currentTree +-- has-flag@3.0.0
43 silly currentTree +-- inherits@2.0.3
43 silly currentTree +-- integer@1.0.7
43 silly currentTree +-- klaw@3.0.0
43 silly currentTree +-- lodash@4.17.11
43 silly currentTree +-- long@4.0.0
43 silly currentTree +-- minimist@0.0.8
43 silly currentTree +-- minipass@2.3.5
43 silly currentTree +-- minizlib@1.1.1
43 silly currentTree +-- mkdirp@0.5.1
43 silly currentTree +-- path@0.12.7
43 silly currentTree +-- prism-media@0.0.3
43 silly currentTree +-- process@0.11.10
43 silly currentTree +-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
43 silly currentTree +-- snekfetch@3.6.4
43 silly currentTree +-- supports-color@5.5.0
43 silly currentTree +-- tar@4.4.7
43 silly currentTree +-- tweetnacl@1.0.0
43 silly currentTree +-- util@0.10.4
43 silly currentTree +-- ws@4.1.0
43 silly currentTree -- yallist@3.0.2
44 silly idealTree chickenbot@0.0.1
44 silly idealTree +-- @types/better-sqlite3@3.1.3
44 silly idealTree +-- @types/integer@1.0.0
44 silly idealTree +-- ansi-styles@3.2.1
44 silly idealTree +-- async-limiter@1.0.0
44 silly idealTree +-- better-sqlite-pool@0.1.2
44 silly idealTree | -- better-sqlite3@4.2.0
44 silly idealTree +-- better-sqlite3@5.0.1
44 silly idealTree | -- integer@2.1.0
44 silly idealTree +-- bindings@1.3.0
44 silly idealTree +-- chalk@2.4.1
44 silly idealTree +-- chownr@1.1.1
44 silly idealTree +-- color-convert@1.9.3
44 silly idealTree +-- color-name@1.1.3
44 silly idealTree +-- discord.js@11.4.2
44 silly idealTree +-- enmap@4.3.3
44 silly idealTree +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
44 silly idealTree +-- fs-minipass@1.2.5
44 silly idealTree +-- graceful-fs@4.1.15
44 silly idealTree +-- has-flag@3.0.0
44 silly idealTree +-- inherits@2.0.3
44 silly idealTree +-- integer@1.0.7
44 silly idealTree +-- klaw@3.0.0
44 silly idealTree +-- lodash@4.17.11
44 silly idealTree +-- long@4.0.0
44 silly idealTree +-- minimist@0.0.8
44 silly idealTree +-- minipass@2.3.5
44 silly idealTree +-- minizlib@1.1.1
44 silly idealTree +-- mkdirp@0.5.1
44 silly idealTree +-- path@0.12.7
44 silly idealTree +-- prism-media@0.0.3
44 silly idealTree +-- process@0.11.10
44 silly idealTree +-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
44 silly idealTree +-- snekfetch@3.6.4
44 silly idealTree +-- supports-color@5.5.0
44 silly idealTree +-- tar@4.4.7
44 silly idealTree +-- tweetnacl@1.0.0
44 silly idealTree +-- util@0.10.4
44 silly idealTree +-- ws@4.1.0
44 silly idealTree -- yallist@3.0.2
45 silly install generateActionsToTake
46 silly diffTrees action count 2
47 silly diffTrees add better-sqlite3@4.2.0
48 silly diffTrees update better-sqlite3@5.0.1
49 silly decomposeActions action count 18
50 silly decomposeActions fetch better-sqlite3@4.2.0
51 silly decomposeActions extract better-sqlite3@4.2.0
52 silly decomposeActions preinstall better-sqlite3@4.2.0
53 silly decomposeActions build better-sqlite3@4.2.0
54 silly decomposeActions install better-sqlite3@4.2.0
55 silly decomposeActions postinstall better-sqlite3@4.2.0
56 silly decomposeActions finalize better-sqlite3@4.2.0
57 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json better-sqlite3@4.2.0
58 silly decomposeActions unbuild better-sqlite3@5.0.1
59 silly decomposeActions remove better-sqlite3@5.0.1
60 silly decomposeActions fetch better-sqlite3@5.0.1
61 silly decomposeActions extract better-sqlite3@5.0.1
62 silly decomposeActions preinstall better-sqlite3@5.0.1
63 silly decomposeActions build better-sqlite3@5.0.1
64 silly decomposeActions install better-sqlite3@5.0.1
65 silly decomposeActions postinstall better-sqlite3@5.0.1
66 silly decomposeActions finalize better-sqlite3@5.0.1
67 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json better-sqlite3@5.0.1
68 silly install executeActions
69 silly doSerial global-install 18
70 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
71 verbose lock using C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-93626228621ab4d1.lock for C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\.staging
72 silly doParallel extract 18
73 silly extract better-sqlite3@4.2.0
74 silly pacote trying better-sqlite3@https://registry.npmjs.org/better-sqlite3/-/better-sqlite3-4.2.0.tgz by hash: sha512-m6vGein6wZWexQ+yaBSHM8MSoSJ9hU2pO+4Ap5THwS0WSro/RKDvwO9a5m1WYvMTh74snnPTVMWeUmiB12UitQ==
75 silly extract better-sqlite3@5.0.1
76 silly pacote trying better-sqlite3@https://registry.npmjs.org/better-sqlite3/-/better-sqlite3-5.0.1.tgz by hash: sha512-dyZk+gDYNPw14maYX5LG/2SCUTiB7jCvETd+bBYqhFyji3oG+UQFN452sUWSjCHCmfg1JtMbLT7WmqB8GLq8Gw==
77 silly pacote better-sqlite3@https://registry.npmjs.org/better-sqlite3/-/better-sqlite3-5.0.1.tgz extracted to C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\.staging\better-sqlite3-f88e10d4 by content address 752ms
78 silly pacote better-sqlite3@https://registry.npmjs.org/better-sqlite3/-/better-sqlite3-4.2.0.tgz extracted to C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\.staging\better-sqlite3-f9484b5f by content address 1795ms
79 silly doReverseSerial unbuild 18
80 silly unbuild better-sqlite3@5.0.1
81 info lifecycle better-sqlite3@5.0.1~preuninstall: better-sqlite3@5.0.1
82 info lifecycle better-sqlite3@5.0.1~uninstall: better-sqlite3@5.0.1
83 verbose unbuild rmStuff better-sqlite3@5.0.1 from C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules
84 info lifecycle better-sqlite3@5.0.1~postuninstall: better-sqlite3@5.0.1
85 silly doSerial remove 18
86 silly remove C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\better-sqlite3
87 silly doSerial move 18
88 silly doSerial finalize 18
89 silly finalize C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\better-sqlite-pool\node_modules\better-sqlite3
90 silly finalize C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\better-sqlite3
91 silly doParallel refresh-package-json 18
92 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\better-sqlite-pool\node_modules\better-sqlite3
93 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\better-sqlite3
94 silly doParallel preinstall 18
95 silly preinstall better-sqlite3@4.2.0
96 info lifecycle better-sqlite3@4.2.0~preinstall: better-sqlite3@4.2.0
97 silly preinstall better-sqlite3@5.0.1
98 info lifecycle better-sqlite3@5.0.1~preinstall: better-sqlite3@5.0.1
99 silly doSerial build 18
100 silly build better-sqlite3@4.2.0
101 info linkStuff better-sqlite3@4.2.0
102 silly linkStuff better-sqlite3@4.2.0 has C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\better-sqlite-pool\node_modules as its parent node_modules
103 verbose linkBins better-sqlite3@4.2.0
104 verbose linkMans better-sqlite3@4.2.0
105 silly build better-sqlite3@5.0.1
106 info linkStuff better-sqlite3@5.0.1
107 silly linkStuff better-sqlite3@5.0.1 has C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules as its parent node_modules
108 verbose linkBins better-sqlite3@5.0.1
109 verbose linkMans better-sqlite3@5.0.1
110 silly doSerial global-link 18
111 silly doParallel update-linked 18
112 silly doSerial install 18
113 silly install better-sqlite3@4.2.0
114 info lifecycle better-sqlite3@4.2.0~install: better-sqlite3@4.2.0
115 verbose lifecycle better-sqlite3@4.2.0~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
116 verbose lifecycle better-sqlite3@4.2.0~install: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\better-sqlite-pool\node_modules\better-sqlite3\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\better-sqlite-pool\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\WorldPainter;C:\Program Files (x86)\Cepstral\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\FFmpeg\bin;;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Local\atom\bin
117 verbose lifecycle better-sqlite3@4.2.0~install: CWD: C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\better-sqlite-pool\node_modules\better-sqlite3
118 silly lifecycle better-sqlite3@4.2.0~install: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node-gyp rebuild' ]
119 silly lifecycle better-sqlite3@4.2.0~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
120 info lifecycle better-sqlite3@4.2.0~install: Failed to exec install script
121 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Yarne\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-93626228621ab4d1.lock for C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite\node_modules\.staging
122 warn discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
123 warn discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
124 warn discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
125 warn discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
126 warn discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
127 warn discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
128 warn discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of uws@^9.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
129 warn chickenbot@0.0.1 No repository field.
130 verbose stack Error: better-sqlite3@4.2.0 install: node-gyp rebuild
130 verbose stack Exit status 1
130 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
130 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
130 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
130 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
130 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
130 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
130 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
130 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
131 verbose pkgid better-sqlite3@4.2.0
132 verbose cwd C:\Users\Yarne\Desktop\CBRewrite
133 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
134 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "better-sqlite3"
135 verbose node v8.9.3
136 verbose npm  v5.5.1
137 error code ELIFECYCLE
138 error errno 1
139 error better-sqlite3@4.2.0 install: node-gyp rebuild
139 error Exit status 1
140 error Failed at the better-sqlite3@4.2.0 install script.
140 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
141 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I do have Python 2.7.0 in my PATH I do have the latest version of node.js and I do have node-gyp installed.

Answer (score -1):

I had an issue when I did this, my issue was that the Visual C++ Build Tools. I suggest installing these (Their installed via the Visual Studio Community 2017 Installer).